# Is it possible to make stylus operate only when finger is toucing it

Tags: android, stylus-pen

i want to ask wheter there is a way to make stylus operate only when finger is touching it, so with my fingers of no changes to be made on screen, and when i do touch it, to work, i hope i was clear, sorry for my bad english.
If this is not possible, is it possible to make android app that wil not hold(wait for my finger to go off) when i am constantly touchg the screen, what i am trying to say is if can operation be done as soon as i touch the screen no matter how much time i am holding it, i dont want app to wait for my finger to go off, best regards to everyone

Comment: My tag stylus got edited, i am not asking about stylus pen, cuz i dont need pen i need stylus custom shaped, like some figure

Comment: What do you mean by stylus? I'm confused.

Comment: stylus pen, but just custom shaped stylus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but here goes:

Try adding a touchListener and then handle the onTouchEvent like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        ...add the code you want to execute...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This way you handle the event as soon as your finger touches the screen

Comment: Thanks man, then the question about stylus drops off
so it is possible to have action as soon as finger touches the screen, i want to avoid the holding in applications, like to disable when you hold finger, as soon as you touch the screen you may hold how long you want but the action was made as it touched the screen, so this is it?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand the part about the stylus :p
But yea, this code will only execute once when the screen is touched.
You can hold your finger on the screen as long as you want, this event will only be triggered the moment the finger touches the screen.
If you release and then press again, the code will execute again.
I hope this is what you were looking for ;)

Comment: yes mate, thank you very very very much, i also have one more question, is it possible to trigger the event when finger is releasing the screen, to both trigger when touch and when released, best regards mate, and thank you for this :)

Comment: Of course! Try to put a switch in the onTouchEvent method, switch on event.getAction() and if MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> finger touches the screen || MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> finger releases the screen. Check out MotionEvent, you'll find some more interesting things. No problem :)

Comment: Big, big thanks mate, but does it depend on how many fingers does screen recognize, can i do what you said with 16 fingers? best regards

Comment: Yes you can, but then you need to use multi-touch gestures. This will be MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP. I'll try to explain a bit more tomorrow, because my day is done ;)

Comment: Thanks man, waiting for the answer so i can start with my project, big thanks and best regards

Comment: So, when you track multiple fingers you should use the "id of the finger". During the touch event (as long as that finger is on the screen), you can track it with it's id. This is stored in the event parameter of the function. But be wary, the index of the ids can change, you should always check for the pointer of the id itself. Hope this helps :) [This is a link to the android developers site about multi-touch gestures, check it out ;)](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html)

Comment: Thanks man, so i just need and multitouch enabled screen and i can work with as many fingers as i want, particulary i want to work with 16, best regards